# How to select check box on click the text using php?

Tags: php

In the image below, if I click either male or female text, I want the checkbox to be checked. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second option is to wrap both checkbox and text in a `label`. It will work too:

```
<label>
    <input id="male_checkbox" name="gender" type="checkbox" value="male" /> Male
</label>
```

Comment: ^--« Quickest method. No `for=` required to rely on an `id` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use label with for attribute:

```
<label for="male_checkbox">Male</label>
<input id="male_checkbox" name="gender" type="checkbox" value="male" />
```

Comment: Your `</label>` is in the wrong spot. It won't check the box.

Comment: My mistake. I'm so used to do it the other way. Will +1 ;-) both methods work actually.

Comment: Thank you all guys... I got the answer. If we given **"for"** command in label tag and given *id* as reference of the check box. <input type="checkbox" name="male" id="male" value="M" onclick="return call_ajax(1)"/><label for="male">Male</label><input type="checkbox" name="female" id="female" value="F" onclick="return call_ajax(1)"/><label for="female">Female</label>

Comment: I must note though, that using `for="male_checkbox"` adds extra characters instead of wrapping it with `<label>...</label>` and relies on an `id` in order to work. It has its pros and cons; don't they all?

Answer (score 3):

`<input type="checkbox" name="male" id="male" value="male"><label for="male">Male</label>`

This will allow the user to click either the name or the checkbox

Do the same for female.